# How to do getattr with method

Tags: python

How would I do the following:

```
instance.method()
```

I know I can do `getattr(instance, method)` to get `instance.method`, but is there a builtin to actually run that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `getattr(instance, method)()`.  `getattr` returns the method object, which you can call with `()` like any other callable.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add a `()` to the end:

```
getattr(instance,method)()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) to create a function that will run that method on the passed instance when executed. However you still have to actually call it on an instance.

```
from operator import methodcaller

call_hello = methodcaller('hello', 'Jack')

call_hello(something)   # same as something.hello('Jack')
```

This is useful when you want to call the same method, for which you don't know the name, on different instances.